# Чи є питомим застовування давального відмінку у словосполученні "мені болить"?

Tags: відмінювання, керування-відмінками

Часто можна зустріти застосування зі словом *«болить»* давального відмінку займенників, як-то у словосполученні *«мені болить…»* замість більш «стандартного» *«у мене болить…»*.

> *Промине, проплине, Наче лист по воді, Все, що в дні молоді Так **боліло мене*** — Іван Франко, XIII, 1954, 82;
>   *Ні, **мене болить**, що Римом зватись може така потвора* — Леся Українка, II, 1951, 507;
>   *О, Україно! Сонце волі! Від ран твоїх **мене болить*** — Павло Тичина, II, 1957, 109. 
>   *Дуже сумував і од того перший раз на Капрі **боліла мені** голова і груди* — Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 334;
>   *Після бійки Семен лежав на соломі, і всі кості **йому боліли*** — Леся Українка, III, 1952, 638;
>   *Тяжко було б описати, як ті сльози **боліли пані** Шумінській* — Наталія Кобринська, Вибрані твори, 1954, 16;
>   ***Болить і йому*** кривда, що її чинить над посполитими шляхта — Панч, Гомоніла Україна, 1954, 420;

СУМ [пропонує](http://sum.in.ua/s/bolity) таку граматику:

> у кого, рідше **кому**, розм., рідко **кого**, також без додатка.

Але це ж — СУМ, з усіма його недоліками. :)

Власне, запитання: чи керує дієслово *болить* давальним відмінком керованих іменників чи займенників?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хоч автор запитання і вважає, що гарна відповідь має посилатися більше, ніж на одне джерело), та оскільки це запитання давно очікує бодай на якусь відповідь, а я натрапила на цю інформацію, то поділюсь.

Олена Курило в посібнику **"Уваги до сучасної української літературної мови"** відзначає такі

> [**§ 14. Особливості у вживанні
>   датива**](http://kurylo.wikidot.com/14-osoblyvosti-u-vzhyvanni-datyva):
>
> **У народній мови инколи подибуємо конструкцію з *дативом* там, де літературна мова здебільшого вживає прийменника `у` (`в`) *із
>   генітивом***.
>
> Про такі конструкції з дієсловами, як ***`брати`***, ***`видирати
>   кому`***, див. при дієсловах, § 6, ст. 113.
>
> Приклади: — *Язика не поверне, наче він `йому` повстяний Ном*. 11736.
>   *Я `їм` був у кумах* Шух. 74.
>
> *Пани б’ються, а `мужикам` чуприни трясуться* Приказка. *Хто мастить, `тому` віз не скрипить*. Приказка. *Ноги `йому` без стремен так
>   теліпаються* Кв. *Пика `йому` не вмита, волосся розкудовчене* Кв. *Він
>   як угледів дівчинку, аж очі `йому` засвітились* MB. *І брови `йому`
>   чорні і уста червоні* MB. *Помер `їм` батько. Руки `їм` довгі, тонкі,
>   як цівки* Лев. *Очі `йому` веселі й бистрі* MB. *Голова `йому`
>   нечесана, чуб непідголений* Кв. *Щоб `моєму` миленькому волики
>   пристали* Чуб. V, 403. *Вже `вдівоньці` пшениця поспіла* ib. 856. *Це
>   родич нашій `паламарці`* Котл. *Колядники беруться за руки, топірці в
>   руках `їм`* Гн. Кол. і щ. II, 331.
>
> В останньому уривкові, де при дативі є речівник-підмет, датив місцями
>   набирає значіння приналежности. Виразнішій відтінок приналежности
>   датив має в такій, наприклад, фразі: — *Це родич `нашій паламарці`*
>   Котл.

Окремий розділ у **§ 6. Особливості в конструкціях із особовими дієсловами** мовознавець відводить питанню

> [**2. Датив при
>   дієсловах**](http://kurylo.wikidot.com/6-osoblyvosti-v-konstruktsiiakh-iz-osobovymy-diieslovamy#toc13).
>
> ***`Дякувати`***, ***`віддячити`***, ***`вибачати`***, ***`-чити`***, ***`простити`*** *`кому`* (а не зросійська кого): — *Чого сидиш, Марусенько, чом не дякуєш `батеньку`* Метл. 225. *Подякує `мені`* Нар.
>   186. *Буду завсегда дякувати `вам`*26. (Шевченко помилково об’єднав одним акузативом два дієслова, що мають по собі різні відмінки: —
>   *Того знають і дякують люди*). *Віддячим `діявольським синам`, — гукали громадяне* Гр. *`Подорожньому` і бог вибачає* Ном. *Скажіть їм,
>   щоб простили `мені` бурлаці за мою смерть на чужині* Лев. *Я знаю, що
>   ти мене вірно любиш, а я тільки пожартувала, — збач `мені` те* MB. У
>   західніх говірках також: — *Вибачайте `на мене`* Шух. 238.
>
> ***`Болить`***, ***`кортить`***, ***`свербить`*** *`кому`* (*`і кого`* див. нижче при акузативі): — *`Кому` кортить, `тому` й **болить***
>   Ном. *Ой **болить** `мені` та й головонька* Кл. Кв. 132. *Не
>   **болить** `мені` головонька* Гн. Колом. II, 57. *Чужий біль `нікому` не **болить*** Ном. *Зав’яжи мені головоньку, бо то `мені` **болить**
>   дуже* Чуб. V, 87. *`Козакам` кортіла воля, а не віра* Кул. VI, 337.
>   *Кортить `тобі` таки домівка* Гр. *Ви `мені` і за вухом не свербите* Гр.
>
> ***`Зневіритися`*** *`чому`* (і *`в чому`*): — *Зневірившись тому `щастю` в своїй долі, тут ми дали йому знов віру* Кул. VI, 475.
>
> ***`Сміятися`***, ***`насміятися`***, ***`глумитися`*** *`кому`*, *`чому`* див. при генітиві `сміятися з чого`.
>
> При дієсловах ***`брати`***, ***`взяти`***, ***`видирати`*** та инших
>   близького значіння маємо в народній мові здебільшого датив, де
>   літературна мова вживає переважно прийм. у(в) із генітивом: —
>   *`Вовкові` барана з горла не видереш* Ном. 4853. *Ой я візьму `багатому`, убогому даю*. Пісня. *Він пожалував і не брав `їм` мами*
>   Яв. 9.

Comment: Ого, дуже дякую, про аспекти давального відмінку із другої половини відповіді я й не чув ніколи.

Comment: @bytebuster, і я теж)